# get single object from a hasMany relation without doing '()' on relation in laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
class Document extends Model {
....
    public function files() { 
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentFile::class, 'document_id'); 
    }

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->files()->whereSome_condition('some')->first();
    }
....
}
```

This is my Document model. It has `hasMany files` relation. also there is another relation '`file`' which returns single object filtering through some conditions from first relation '`files` '.

```
dd($document->file());
```

returns that object which is fine but,

```
dd($document->file);
```

gives "LogicException in HasAttributes.php line 403: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation " exception.

Can anyone tell me why $document->file is not working in this case ? And what can be the solution for my problem.
I don't want to write extra set of `()` everywhere i use this relation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the second relationship, as the exception was saying,  the relationship method must return a object of Relation. If you want to retrieve first record of related model, you can do it like this:

```
dd($document->files->first());
```

Answer (score 0):

do it :

```
public function file() { 
        return $this->hasOne(DocumentFile::class, 'document_id')->whereSome_condition('some'); 
    }
```

it work by :

```
$document->file
```